# Matching a column from one data frame to another one by unique values of other colums

Tags: r, loops, mapping, unique

I have two data frames:

```
>old 
response    RT  sNumber blockNo
tiger       170       1       1
tornado     36        1       2
tiger       43        1       3
squire      34        2       1
tiger       48        2       2
tornado     49        2       3
tornado     45        3       1
mouse       66        3       2
tiger       75        3       3

>new
response    sNumber blockNo
tiger             1       1
tornado           1       2
squire            2       1
tiger             2       2
tornado           3       1
mouse             3       2
tiger             3       3
```

In **new** there are fewer raws. I want to copy *RT* column from **old** and perform a mapping by *response* column to **new** by keeping correct values of *RT* corresponding to the unique *sNumber* and *blockNo*. It should look like this:

```
>new2
response    RT  sNumber blockNo
tiger      170        1       1
tornado     36        1       2
squire      34        2       1
tiger       48        2       2
tornado     45        3       1
mouse       66        3       2
tiger       75        3       3
```

Usually for mapping I use this loop:

```
for(wrd in unique(old$response)){
    new$RT[new$response == wrd] <- old$RT[old$response == wrd]
    }
```

However, in this particular case it messes up all RT values since it adds up them successively without checking for the unique *blockNo* and *sNumber*. How should I perform the mapping of  *RT* in a way that I have described?

Comment: Check out `mapvalues` function in the `plyr` package

Answer (score 3):

To match values in multiple columns in two data.frames and add extra data from one to the other, you can use `merge`.

```
 merge(old, new, by = c("response", "sNumber", "blockNo"), all = FALSE)
  response sNumber blockNo  RT
1    mouse       3       2  66
2   squire       2       1  34
3    tiger       1       1 170
4    tiger       2       2  48
5    tiger       3       3  75
6  tornado       1       2  36
7  tornado       3       1  45
```

This checks if values in all named columns specified in the `by=` argument match between the data.frames. When they all match, additional columns in either data.frame are added to the merged data.

The `all = FALSE` argument controls whether the resulting data should contain only the rows that matched in selected columns between the two data.frames (default). If `all = TRUE`, the merged data.frame will contain all rows present in the data.frames.

Comment: The all argument is set to FALSE automatically.

Comment: @lmo Yes, but I felt it needed to be specified to better address the question.

Comment: Better to just explain this this in the text something like: "there is an argument all, that is set to FALSE by default.  It happens that this is what we want in this situation... in other circumstances, it can be set to TRUE to retrieve all observations from both  data.frames."

Comment: @lmo Added. Thanks for the suggestion. Constructive.

Comment: @nya Thank you a lot! It worked